# Webservice not working in Airflow docker container

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have created a docker container for airflow using a Dockerfile. I need to run two webservice when anyone run the docker image. I am using ENTRYPOINT to execute run the web service through entrypoint script. While I am running the docker container only one web service is running and other is not, but if I am going inside the docker container and running the same script, then both the webservice is running.

I want to run airflow services 'airflow webserver' and 'airflow scheduler'

```
>entrypoint.sh file 
-----------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash
airflow initdb
airflow webserver -D
airflow scheduler -D
exec "$@"
-----------------------------

>Dockerfile
-----------------------------------------------
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL "Created_By"="------"
#Python installation
##pip3
RUN apt update -y && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils 
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev && \
    pip install wtforms==2.2.1 && \
    pip install apache-airflow && \
    pip install apache-airflow[mysql] 

WORKDIR /script/
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod -R 0705 /script/
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

---

I am not getting why only one service is running

Comment: you may not need the -D part in the entrypoint script. At least puckel's docker-airflow doesn't --> https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh

Comment: Actually both the service "webserver and scheduler" will running continues in the shell, so we can't run 2nd command in same shell, that is why I used -D.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the container in detached mode instead:

```sh
docker run -d <IMAGE>
```

Then enter the container like so:

```sh
docker exec -it <CONTAINER> bash
```

This worked for me with your code as is.

---

**Side note**: you shouldn't run multiple services within one container. From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/):

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
>   using one service per container.

See [puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) for an example implementation of Airflow utilizing separate containers for each service.